# Windows Service Bus with SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, wcf, service, sql-server-2008-r2, servicebus

I'm working with the Windows Service Bus v1.0

When an update is performed on a certain table in my SQL Server 20008 R2 database, I want a trigger to send a message to a certain queue.

On that queue a WCF service is listening. When it captures the message, certain processing will be preformed.

I have been looking around, but I can't seem to find a sample.

Can anyone help me?
Thx

Comment: I have already several services that listen to different queues. But these are created in C#. Now I want my database to send a message to one of those queues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19954/Execute-NET-Code-under-SQL-Server-2005

I'm going to try this way and hope it works.